# NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath unable to overwrite existing file in Swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, nsfilemanager, xcode7

Hello I'm upgrading my existing code to Swift 2, and I need some help with the copy of a file inside the DocumentDirectoy.

This is converted code I'm using to check if the file exists, and if it does, we should copy it either way, but it keeps returning an error saying the file exists, which it is true, but we need to overwrite it.

```
func copyXMLFile()
    {
    // Get a reference for the Document directory
    let rootPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] 
    // Get a reference for the data.xml file
    xmlPathInDocument = rootPath.stringByAppendingString("data.xml")
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(xmlPathInDocument){
        print("xml file exists")

                let xmlPathInBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "xml")!
        do {
            // copy file from main bundle to documents directory
            print("copy")
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(xmlPathInBundle, toPath: xmlPathInDocument)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // Catch fires here, with an NSErrro being thrown
            print("error occurred, here are the details:\n \(error)")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // copy the file either way

        let xmlPathInBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "xml")!
        do {
            // copy file from main bundle to documents directory
            print("copy")
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(xmlPathInBundle, toPath: xmlPathInDocument)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // Catch fires here, with an NSErrro being thrown
            print("error occurred, here are the details:\n \(error)")
        }

    }

 }
```

error occurred, here are the details:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 516.)" UserInfo=0x7a67b680
>   {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/User1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0E591E5B-2E2F-4CCB-9099-95CE1EA3F557/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E3C8FAE4-703D-46CA-AC37-A1C96A74E6BE/myApp.app/data.xml,
>   NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Copy ), NSFilePath=/Users/User1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0E591E5B-2E2F-4CCB-9099-95CE1EA3F557/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E3C8FAE4-703D-46CA-AC37-A1C96A74E6BE/myApp.app/data.xml,
>   NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/User1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0E591E5B-2E2F-4CCB-9099-95CE1EA3F557/data/Containers/Data/Application/09F690B3-BDD8-4482-ADDE-E33F30D4B873/Documentsdata.xml,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7a67dd80 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   File exists"}

Please HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `NSFileManagerDelegate` and the delegate method

```
optional func fileManager(_ fileManager: NSFileManager,
  shouldProceedAfterError error: NSError,
        copyingItemAtURL srcURL: NSURL,
                   toURL dstURL: NSURL) -> Bool
```

and return `true`

Alternatively you could use

```
func replaceItemAtURL(_ originalItemURL: NSURL,
               withItemAtURL newItemURL: NSURL,
          backupItemName backupItemName: String?,
                        options options: NSFileManagerItemReplacementOptions,
          resultingItemURL resultingURL: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURL?>) throws
```

Comment: Thank you @vadian, the second option helped!

Comment: When testing my app in IOS Simulator the copy file process works fine, but when I testing on my device iPhone, I get an error: 



`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x17e8af80 {NSUnderlyingError=0x17e89210 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted", NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A44E5FF5-F52A-45E7-A803-DB6A19F1DB82/myApp.app/data.xml`

Comment: Its this because I'm running the my app on an iPhone using Xcode 7 side load? @vadian

Comment: Never mind, I'm now writing my file to the documents directory and I can handle it from that location just fine.